# How to syntax check portable POSIX shell scripts?

Tags: shell, posix, sh, static-analysis

The following shell script executes well when provided `/bin/true` for the first argument, but may otherwise fail with a **syntax error during execution!**

```
#!/bin/sh
if $1 ; then exit; fi
/tmp/asdf <<< ASDF # Something with syntax error in POSIX
```

Surely some syntax errors (if not all?) can be avoided by static checking? **How do I statically check whether a given [Shell Command Language](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html) script is syntactically valid?**

**EDIT:** Checking for syntax errors in Bash scripts has been answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171924/how-do-i-check-syntax-in-bash-without-running-the-script).

**EDIT #2:** Note that [Bash fails](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36888649/6123289) to properly check whether the syntax adheres to POSIX even when executed with the `+B` and `--posix` flags in addition to `-n`.

Comment: http://shellcheck.net is a useful resource and as I recall you can download a standalone tool.

Comment: @tripleee Please reconsider whether this really is a duplicate.

Comment: The duplicate asks for a Bash solution but the answers are fine for POSIX, too. The duplicate link could go the other way if the shellcheck.net answer is migrated here, but I don't really see the need -- this duplicate works as a signpost for people searching for a POSIX solution.

Comment: @tripleee Actually this question appears to be more of a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28654973/test-for-posix-shell-compliance) (which is also a duplicate of [this one on Unix&Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48786/how-can-i-test-for-posix-compliance-for-shell-scripts)).

Comment: @jotik Nominally a better question, but its sole answer is rather unsatisfactory.

Comment: The *syntax* is fine; using a parameter expansion to supply an entire command is not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All POSIX-compatible [Shell Command Language](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html) shells support the [`set -n`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set) built-in which can be used to check the syntax of the script. Therefore it is possible to prepend

```
set -n
```

to your code to syntax check it. Note also that standard [sh](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html) utility is also required to support a command-line `-n` flag, which has equivalent semantics to using `set -n`. Bash and possibly other shells also support this command-line flag. Therefore you can simply run the following to syntax check your script:

```
sh -n yourScriptFilename.sh
```

**WARNING:** This does not give you a guarantee that the script has fully POSIX compatible syntax. For example, Bash allows bashisms (e.g. arrays and `c{a,u}t`) to go unnoticed even when using the `--posix` (and/or `+B`) command line option in addition to `-n` when invoked as `sh`. Other shells might have similar issues.

Comment: Upvote for for POSIX link.

Comment: Why do you ask a question and then duplicate what I said in your own answer? Furthermore it is not useful to change a file, add `set -n` on top before you syntax check it and remove that afterwards. Using `-n` as the command line option, as I told, makes much more sense.

Comment: @hek2mgl Sportsmanship. :-) Note that I didn't accept my own answer, because it doesn't fully answer my question. I urgently need to test a large number of shell scripts for POSIX compatibility (syntax only or as far as possible), which is why I need a reliable means to do it.

Comment: Use `bash --posix -n` for that. If you have a *more* posix compatible shell at the hand, check if it is supports the `-n` option as well. `dash` for example supports the `-n` option.

Comment: The Debian devscripts ([deb package](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=devscripts), [git](https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/collab-maint/devscripts.git)) contain `checkbashisms` to "check whether a /bin/sh script contains any common bash-specific constructs" (see also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3679916/3919155)).

Answer (score 5):

With `bash` you can use `-n`:

```
bash -n file.sh
```

Output:

```
a.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
a.sh: line 3: `if then fi # Something with syntax error'
```

---

Since `bash` supports the `--posix` options you may run

```
bash --posix -n file.sh
```

to perform a posix compatible check. I don't know how posixly correct that mode is in detail.

Comment: I assume this only checks for Bash syntax, but not POSIX?

Comment: Yes, that checks only for bash syntax. However other shells (might) have similar options. `dash` for example supports `-n` as well. Which POSIX shell do you have in mind?

Comment: I think the correct term is "[Shell Command Language](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html)".

Comment: You can run `bash --posix -n`

Comment: I just amended [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36888649/6123289) with a warning about Bash not fully respecting `bash --posix -n`.